# PHP file_get_contents from another server, where is the actual job done?

Tags: php, html

If i am surfing this webpage : www.example1.com/1.php witch PHP code looks like below:

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("http://www.example2.com/2.php");

?>
```

And www.example2.com/2.php code is as follows:

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("http://www.example3.com");

?>
```

And www.example3.com html code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Is the job performed by getting example3.com html code done by server for domain example1.com totally, or is server for domain example2.com allso involved in gathering data from example3.com?

I mean is server for example2.com accually gatehering any data from example3.com, or is it just passing it's own PHP code to example1.com. And then example1.com server running the example2.com PHP code on it's own and gather data from example3.com?

Comment: there's no passing of PHP code, ever.

Comment: It's passing the final html, no php will ever be shown to an outside party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server side preprocessor, so no actual PHP code is passed from one server to another, only the final processed HTML.

So in your example, `www.example3.com` has actual HTML code in it...

`www.example2.com` is simply echoing the content of `www.example3.com`...

`www.example1.com` is echoing the contents of `www.example2.com` which is the processed result of fetching the data from `www.example3.com`.

`example1` never touches `example3` or knows anything about it.